# Why does groovy add print method to every class?

Tags: java, groovy

I have following class:

```
class GroovyTest {
    static class MyClass {
    }

    static main(def s) {
        MyClass.print("hello")
    }
}
```

It prints:

```
hello
```

Why would I need a print method that prints strings in every class?

Furthermore if I do:

```
MyClass.methods.each {println it}
```

It gives me a list of methods that `MyClass` has and `print` is not in the list.

Comment: I guess that it might because of scripting purpose of groovy - You always use it - everywhere. `print` would be printed because it's added at runtime as I guess and `methods` returns only declared methods.

Comment: @Opal I didn't get that. Are you saying that it is added because `print` is needed frequently? Well `println` is already available by default? I don't see any advantage in adding it to `Object`.

Comment: That's just a guess. While other methods from `DefaultGroovyMethods` seems to be reasonable for this one is just a guess as I wrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Groovy adds many methods to classes at runtime.  One of those methods is the print method which is added to java.lang.Object.  See https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/194b29270d418b1b8642f5746a49873018f115c1/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java#L531.  The way DefaultGroovyMethods works is such that the first argument to the method definition in that class represents the type that the method will be added to so something like this...

```
public static someMethod(SomeType o, SomeOtherType arg) {
    // ...
}
```

That means that a method named `someMethod` will be added to `SomeType` and that method accepts an argument of type `SomeOtherType`.

I hope that helps.

Comment: That explains the how but not why? Why would I need such a method in Object class? We already have `DefaultGroovyMethods.println` to print objects. If it were a print method that allowed the object to print itself it could make some sense. But `new MyClass().println()` does nothing.

Comment: You don't "need" it in Object, but it is useful.  Groovy provides lots of things that you don't "need", but are useful.  You don't need dynamic dispatch, for example, but there are good reasons you might want it.  The print method is a convenient way to do a common thing.  There is no reason that you have to use it, but a lot of folks do and find it useful.  You can just treat it as shorthand for System.out.println().  It isn't exactly that, but treating it that way is fine.

Comment: Any place that you might call System.out.println(...), replace that with println(...).  Are you looking for examples of where people have done that?

Comment: There is a miscommunication here. I agree that `println` is useful and that it is better than `System.out.println`. It is defined in `DefaultGroovyMethods` and is available *anywhere* within a Groovy script. I fail to see why add we need to add it to every class? In what case would someone want to write new `MyClass.println('hello')` instead of `println('hello')`?

Comment: There is no reason to ever do `MyClass.println('hello')` instead of `println('hello')`.  There is also no reason to do `println('h' + 'e' + 'l' + 'l' + 'o')`, but you could.  Putting it in Object means that it is available everywhere you might want it.  If you want it, it is there, and if you don't want it, there isn't really a cost of it being there.  If it weren't in Object then in order to have it somewhere you would have to have a way to express that you wanted it there.  Object is a convenient way to make it available everywhere.  It is kind of like notify().

Comment: Groovy doesn't do anything specifically just so you can call `MyClass.println('hello')`.  That is a goofy thing to do.  Groovy adds the `println` method to `Object` so you can call it from anywhere and because it is added to `Object` you can call it on any `Object`, including a `Class` object  because `Class` extends `Object`.

Comment: Ah I get it now. I was under the impression that `println` is a static method made available by default import. Hence I thought adding it to `Object` would be redundant. But there is no default import. It becomes available by being added to every class via `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

Groovy adds a bunch of useful methods to the class Object, which means they are available to any object. Even classes, which are objects themselves. That is why you can do `[].println()`.

This is strategy is used because Groovy, nor Java, have the concept of builtin functions like Python or PHP, which have `print` and `echo`, respectively. There are only objects and methods. There is no builtin `println` which you can simply call from nowhere. This is one of the ways to add a global-ish `println` function.

Seems like it is a builtin function in [Ruby](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_builtin_functions.htm), also, as `puts`.